# How to check if the current time lies between the two times that open and close in utc timing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, momentjs, utc

I am trying to check if the current time lies between the two timings open and close.
based on that,I have return the color,tried code but getting wrong result,input timings are in 24 hours clock.

```
const calculateMarketIndicator = (startTime, endTime) => {
  let color;
  var startTime = startTime;
  var endTime = endTime;
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let currentUTC = moment(currentDate).utc();
  startDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  startDate.setHours(startTime.split(":")[0]);
  startDate.setMinutes(startTime.split(":")[1]);
  let startUTC = moment(startDate).utc();
  endDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  endDate.setHours(endTime.split(":")[0]);
  endDate.setMinutes(endTime.split(":")[1]);
  let endUTC = moment(endDate).utc();

  let value = currentUTC.isBetween(startUTC, endUTC);
  if (value) {
    color = COLORS.green;
  } else {
    color = COLORS.red;
  }
  return color
};
```

```
and this is my input 
1) 
calculateMarketIndicator( "22:00", "21:59") getting  red
calculateMarketIndicator( "14:30" "21:00") getting  green
calculateMarketIndicator(  "23:01" "05:00") getting  red
```

Answer (score 0):

The code using moment.js is difficult to follow. Consider using plain JS to create dates with the required UTC times, then compare to the test date, e.g.

```js
// Determine if time of supplied date is on or after start and
// on or before end times
// All calculations in UTC
// Assumes start is before end and are valid times
function isBetweenUTC(start, end, date = new Date()) {
  // Get time parts
  let [startHr, startMin] = start.split(/\D/);
  let [endHr, endMin] = end.split(/\D/);
  // Copy supplied date
  let temp = new Date(date);
  // Create dates for required UTC time
  let startUTC = new Date(temp.setUTCHours(startHr, startMin,0,0));
  let endUTC = new Date(temp.setUTCHours(endHr, endMin,0,0));
  console.log(endUTC);
  // Return true if  date is on or after start and
  // on or before end
  return date >= startUTC && date <= endUTC;
}

// Examples
let start = "21:00";
let end = "22:59";

[new Date(),                              // Now
 new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 4, 15, 19, 59)), // Before
 new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 4, 15, 21,  0)), // During
 new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 4, 15, 22, 10)), // During
 new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 4, 15, 22, 59)), // During
 new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 4, 15, 23,  0))  // After
 ].forEach(
   d => console.log(d.toISOString() + ' ' + isBetweenUTC(start, end, d))
 );
```

I think it's more common for a duration to be expressed as 22:00 to 23:00 rather than 22:59. Then the test is `date >= start && date < end`.

Comment: if I pass  "22:00" "21:59" ,it is converted to utc like this 2023-04-19T22:00:00.000Z 2023-04-19T21:59:00.000Z@RobG